# Number of ways to generate an element in a finite abelian group

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a finite abelian group $G$ of order $n$.

What is the maximum number of minimal ways to construct a non zero element $g \in G$ from elements in $G$?

By "way" and "minimal", I mean the following. A *way* to construct $g$ can be described by a subset $H \subset G$ that is summed to form $g$. $H$ is considered *minimal* if there is no subset of $H$ such that the sum of this subset is equal to the zero element. Perhaps there is a better way to name this, but minimal is the best I could come up with.

**Example:**

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}^2 \mod 2$, and $g = (0,1)$. Then there are two minimal ways to construct $g$. $H_1 = \{(0,1)\}$ and $H_2 = \{(1,0),(1,1)\}$. For any $g$ there are maximally 2 ways, so 2 is the value I'm looking for.

For $G = \mathbb{Z}^3 \mod 2$, I got 8 (identical for all nonzero $g$).

**Thoughts so far:**

At first I was thinking it should be related to the minimal generating set of $G$, which is bounded in size by $\log_2 n$ ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226931/why-is-the-minimum-size-of-a-generating-set-for-a-finite-group-at-most-log-2-n)). But when I partially worked out the case of $\mathbb{Z}^2_4$ I was getting numbers greater than $n$. I also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447984/number-of-ways-a-group-element-of-a-finite-group-can-be-written-as-a-given-word) stack answer but I honestly can't tell if it's related to my question or not.

Is there an easy way to bound this value?